# Struggling with installing Audacious part 2

Tags: unix, cygwin

So I did install pkg-config just fine, I even saw signs that I installed it correctly. However, when I tried to compile Audacious again with cygwin, I get this message:
`Package 'glib-2.0', required by 'virtual:world', not found  Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you installed software in a non-standard prefix.  Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GLIB_CFLAGS and GLIB_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config. See the pkg-config man page for more details.`

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

looks at package list on
https://cygwin.com/packages/package_list.html

looking for `glib` you will find a package named `libglib2.0-devel`
Have you installed it ?

It contains

```
usr/lib/pkgconfig/glib-2.0.pc
```

see
https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/libglib2.0-devel/libglib2.0-devel-2.54.3-1